# What is actually the center of semi dihedral group $SD_{24}$?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I got confused whether the center of semi dihedral group $SD_{24}$ is just ${e,a^6}$ or ${e,a^3,a^6,a^9}$ since all of elements are commute and it also equals to its inverse.

My definition for semi dihedral group:

$$SD_{8n}=\langle a,b\mid a^{4n}=b^2=1,bab=a^{2n-1}\rangle, $$

where $n\geq2$.

Comment: I only know of semidihedral groups of order $2^n$. What is your definition?

Comment: My definition: $SD_{8n}=<a,b|a^{4n}=b^2=1,bab=a^{2n-1}>$ where $n\geq2$

Comment: The centre is cyclic of order $4$. Since $a^3$ commutes with $b$, it is central. Since $a^4$ does not commute with $b$, neither $b$ nor $a^4$ may lie in the centre.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven thank you so much for your response. It is really helpful.